# Linux VSCode unable to use

Tags: linux, ssh

when I was trying to open vscode on ubuntu, it always showed this blank page, whatever i chose any option. I tried to uninstall and reinstall vscode but still appeared like this.

also, i tried to connect remote server in linux, but it always stucked at this password area. it didnt allow me to put password. I suppose it had some problem on my system. I am wondering how to fix it. If anyone who can help me out i will be much

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal, type `code .` edit the post to include the output of the terminal when you've run the command. *DO NOT* post a screenshot of the text; copy it and paste it.

Comment: When I enter code. there is no code appeared just popped up vscode interface with blank

Comment: I just tried running it myself and it forks directly to the background... that's odd. Might be a problem with the rendering. Try `code --disable-gpu`.